# 脚底抹油－开溜 translate into English

Tags: translation

Can someone help me to translate 脚底抹油－开溜 because when I'm using google translate the sentence is so weird.

Comment: This kind of expression is known as 歇后语 in Chinese: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xiehouyu

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If something bad happened, you can `脚底抹油` (`put oil on the sole of foot`) , and then `开溜` (`start to slip away quickly`).

In short, it means `expeditious retreat`.

BTW: Here's another statement as `脚底抹油 - 溜之大吉`, which has a similar meaning.

Comment: this is in iciba, just enter 脚底抹油

Answer (score 1):

This phrase is a Chinese idiom that simply means to escape or to avoid (from negative consequences/liabilities/etc).

Answer (score 1):

I think it's just meaning skip away.

Answer (score -1):

It means run away quickly as if there is oil on the sole of your foot

Comment: It also means slip away. For example, you could use it to describe a thief